# Can the Interpreter pattern be as simple as parsing a config file?

Tags: design-patterns

Hopefully not a stupid question, however is the act of parsing a config file and making the contents available to a program a simple example of the Interpreter pattern?

All of the examples I find seem to imply that the Interpreter pattern is for more complicated situations (such as a interpreting a formal language with a complex grammar) but there doesn't seem to be any reason why it couldn't cover much more simpler cases as well.

Comment: How do you define a config file? A list of key value pairs or somethig with additional structure, different sections for example? Can a key have multiple values? Are there different types of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key benefits of Patterns is as a **common language to describe well known problems together with their solutions**.

The canonical example of Interprepter is a simple arithmetic expression evaluator, where an input expression is parsed into a composite tree. Then apply `execute()` on the head node to calculate the value of the expression, with each sub-expression (at the branch nodes) contributing its part.

If your config file is written in a simple language, like XML or JSON, then Interpreter pattern seems an overkill, since there is no real "grunt work" to interpret the language statements (ie parsing) to be done. It may be academically useful to observe some similarities with Interpreter (as you have done) but **may be misleading to others** to comment in your code that you are using **Interpreter Pattern**.

However, if your configuration is expressed in a more complex language, involving for example conditionals, loops etc, then for sure **Interpreter** may be reasonable. The Interpreter Pattern code will include a "parser" for the language which in turn will create some form of useful tree structure. Then the tree would be used to configure as needed by loading modules and inter-dependencies etc or whatever your application needs. This is **Interpreter**.